# render data into an array using the map issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

im trying to render data into an array so that the data can be viewed in a chart in react native.

There seems to be an issue regarding maximum

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View,Button,Text } from 'react-native';
import { LineChart, XAxis, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts'
import n_data from './data'


class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {data:[]}
  
 
  }


  render() {

    const restructuredData = n_data.map( (name) =>   this.setState({data:name.volume}) )
  

    return (
      <View>
     <Text> {this.state.data}  </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

my sample data is in n_data and looks like this

```
const n_data = [{"timestamp":"2011-08-18T00:00:00Z","volume":"5","spot_volume":"5","derivative_volume":"0"}]
```

Comment: i belive the issue to be with the this.setState

Comment: what is the error your having, and you are trying to render an array as Text, this is not okey

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function like this. Your `restructuredData` will eventually lead to a Maximum call depth error as the setState method is called multiple times and will cause the component to re-render equal to the length of your n_data array.

```
  <View>
        {n_data &&
          n_data.map((item) => (
            <Text key = {item.volume}>{item.volume}</Text>
          ))}
      </View>
```

Also, you're trying to render an array as a Text component here

```
<Text> {this.state.data} </Text>
```

which is not correct.

***Update***:

This is how you can update the state

```
restructuredData = n_data => {
    let updated_n_data = [];
    // Object.values(objName) gives the values of an object
    Object.values(n_data).map(item => {
      updated_n_data = updated_n_data.concat(item.volume);
    });
    this.setState({
      data: updated_n_data,
    });
  };
```

Comment: thank you for the response i dont want to render the data into a text, (the above was when i was testing with one value), i just want to add it into a array into the state

Comment: hey thanks, the data is not showing up when i console.log(this.state.data

Comment: Where are you trying to write the console.log in your code? Try to write in componentDidUpdate as if you'll try to console in restructuredData you'll get an empty array as setState is asynchronous.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@ej97/smelly-tortillas - my snack link of what the code looks like

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the data outside of the component (no need to use setState here) and then just set it as your inital state inside the constructor.
this.setState() usually triggers a render. When you call it directly from inside the render function there will probably be an endless loop.

The other thing is that your trying to render an array as Rohit already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are having because you are resetting state Ina render function which will try to re-render the component. You will need to modify your component, here is a quick example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View,Button,Text } from 'react-native';
import { LineChart, XAxis, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts'
import n_data from './data'


class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    let data= null;
    n_data.map(name=>{data=name.volume});
    this.state = {data}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
     <Text> {this.state.data}  </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: What doesn’t work? Does it throw error or it simply doesn’t display anything? Please be more specific.

Comment: my bad , the data does not go into the the data variable, i added a function to preview the data but nothing shows

Comment: Perhaps try logging in constructor and see if n_data and data populated correctly. If you can post a snack example I can look.

Comment: Hi @SaachiTech thanks for the reply my snack link snack.expo.io/@ej97/smelly-tortillas